# Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django

Здравствуйте. 
Использую в приложении Crispy Forms, и не совсем понимаю. как сделать:

Вот простая форма:

```
class QualificationAnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer_text = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['answer_text']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QualificationAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = "POST"
        self.helper.form_action = reverse('create_answer', args=['question.id'])

        self.helper.layout.append(
            HTML("<button style='width: 15rem' class='col-md-offset-5 btn btn-custom btn-sm btn-block' type='submit'>"
                "%s</button>" % _('Answer')
                )
            )
        self.helper.form_class = ''
        self.helper.label_class = 'hidden'
        self.helper.field_class = ''
```

и мне нужно создать form_action, исходя из вопроса. на котроый идёт ответ:

```
    self.helper.form_action = reverse('create_answer', args=['question.id'])
```

но откуда мне взять этот qusetion.id ?

Вот вьюха, в которую я тяну эту форму:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'detail'
    template_name = 'qualification/question.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = QualificationAnswerForm()
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Question, pk=self.kwargs.get("question_id"))
```

вот вьюха, которой хочу обработать форму:

```
class CreateAnswerView(LoginRequired, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'qualification/question.html'
    model = Answer
    fields = ['answer_text']
    message = _('Thank you! your answer has been posted.')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        ...
        return super(CreateAnswerView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if qa_messages:
            messages.success(
                self.request, self.message)
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['question_id']})
```

Подскажите, как правильно это сделать ?

Важно использовать CrispyForms, а не создавать форму внутри шаблона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за проявленное внимание и оказанную помомощь.
Решил так:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = QualificationAnswerForm()
        form.helper.form_action = reverse('create_answer', kwargs={'question_id': self.kwargs.get("question_id")})
        context['form'] = form
        return context
```